# Collision Detection between a Oval and Arc

Tags: java, collision-detection, paint

I am writing a simple game, or so it seemed. I created a class that draws a `Arc2D` (half a circle shape), that same class will repaint the arch as the mouse move.

[image]

Then I created a new class that draws ovals. This class has some simple mathematics to move the ovals on the screen. The movement of the ovals are not very important. So now that this is done I want to detect if the Oval collides with the arc(half a circle, `Only the arc line`) at any point.

What I have attempted is making the oval a Rectangle and use the intersect method. This code is in the draw method for the arc.

```
Arc2D temp= new Arc2D.Double(200, 200, 100, 100, angle, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);
MasterOval m = new MasterOval();
Rectangle r1 = m.bounds();//This gets the bounds of the oval
if(r1.intersects(temp.getBounds()))
    System.out.println("hit");//display if intersects
```

For some reason I cant figure out why it will not display the word `hit` when it collides with the arc. Is there a way to see if they intercect? This is all code I can provide due to privacy policies. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if your `MasterOval` class implements the `Shape` interface or not, but if it does (if it doesn't, consider using `Ellipse2D.Double` or something of that sort), the easiest way (standard perhaps ?) of checking for collision between `Shape` instances is using `Area`:

```
Shape1 shape1 = new Arc2D.Double(...);
Shape2 shape2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(...);

Area area1 = new Area(shape1);
Area area2 = new Area(shape2);

if (area1.intersect(area2)) {
    ...
}
```