# Collision Detection Between An Ellipse2D Object And An Arc2d Object

Tags: java, object, collision-detection, shapes

Before I start, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449603/collision-detection-between-a-oval-and-arc) post but it doesn't seem to work for me. I am trying to check for collision between an Arc2d object and an Ellipse2D object. The collision works but it turns the objects into rectangles.

```
public Arc2D a;
public Ellipse2D e;

public void aStuff() {
    a = new Arc2D.Double(((getWidth() / 2) - (250 / 2)), (getHeight() - 135), 250, 265, 0, 180, Arc2D.CHORD);
}

public void eStuff() {
    e = new Ellipse2D.Double((getWidth() / 2), y, 52, 55);
}

public boolean collisionCheck() {
    if (a.getBounds2D().intersects(e.getBounds2d())) { // This is where it turns them into rectangles.
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my timer which changes the position of "a" so it collides with "e" it will check the boolean return value and do something.

```
y += 5;
if (collisionCheck()) {
    ...
}
```

But at the moment, I can't get the checking part to work properly. What can I change. I have tried using the shape object and using the area but it gives me an error saying it cannot return a void value from boolean. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found `Area`s to be much more useable for doing shape collision than using the actual `Shape`s themselves, and I built a utility for building Arcs as Areas [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/util/ShapeUtils.java). If you are interested, you might want to take a look at this and `Area`.

As for your second question, if you get rid of the else { ... } block in your collisionCheck method and instead just return false right after the if {} block, this may fix your problem.

Comment: I tried using area but it gives me this error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to boolean.